# mc_eid showing [UNIQID] in MailChimp link after enabling tracking

Tags: url, google-analytics, mailchimp

I have a number of subscribers which were all added to a MailChimp list through the API. Now I want to launch a campaign to a subset of these subscribers.

MailChimp allows one to add link tracking to a campaign so that you can track clicks from those individual subscribers in Google Analytics. When link tracking for a certain campaign is turned on, MailChimp should automatically add two tags to each URL in your campaign:

- `mc_cid` is the internal MailChimp-generated ID for the specific campaign.
- `mc_eid` is the unique, MailChimp-generated ID for each subscriber.

This is indeed the case. The underlying URL that is generated by MailChimp then contains following campaign parameters:

`/?utm_source=...&utm_campaign=...&utm_medium=email&utm_term=...&mc_cid=ce9f1a2469&mc_eid=[UNIQID]`

Unfortunately, the value `[UNIQID]` assigned to `mc_eid` is not the correct one. It's even not a value, it's really a parameter.

Is there a setting that I am overlooking? Since I pass my subscriber to MailChimp through the API and they all have a valid `unique_email_id`, this shouldn't be happening?

Anyone knows how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

So the `mc_eid` is by default set to `[UNIQID]`, so rather than using that default merge tag, I added to my links a custom url tag with that merge tag as value.

So I went ahead to edit my campaign, in the place where the link appears, I edited it and added custom values having the merge tags I wanted, in this case the one for uniqid and the email.

[image]

You can find a list of available merge tags [here](https://mailchimp.com/en/help/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet/).

This is a hack to be able to overcome the issue, but it doesn't fix it. If someone has a better way to approach this problem I'll gladly hear about it.